# Unable to access the value of extra-vars in debug statement

Tags: jenkins, ansible

The below command is executed via Jenkins but I am not able to print the value of "JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER" in my debug statement.

```
ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/inventory/development/hosts /etc/ansible/test.yml -e JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER
```

**The task content looks like the following:**

```
# cat tasks/main.yml
---
- debug:
    msg: "{{ JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER }}"
```

**Jenkins console log shows the below result:**

```
# ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/inventory/development/hosts /etc/ansible/test.yml -e JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER

[SSH] executing...

PLAY [Testing] *****************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ""
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


[SSH] completed
[SSH] exit-status: 0

Finished: SUCCESS
```

**Additional Info:**

- Tried **--extra-vars** and **-e** both doesn't seem to work
- Tried with "**JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER**" and without quotes but both doesn't give any results.

Comment: did you try with quotes "JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER"

Comment: Yes tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: BUILD_NUMBER is jenkins in-built variable, when a job is executed via jenkins this number will get generated.

Answer (score 0):

`-e` doesn't seem to work for me either. Try doing `--extra-vars "JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER"` instead.

Comment: Okie, then try --extra-vars "JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}"